# Static Semantic vs dynamic Semantic

Tags: java

I'm not so sure about semantic.

```
int x=1
```

Is this static semantic?

```
int x=1+1
```

Is this dynamic semantic?

Comment: What do *static* and *dynamic* mean in your question?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I hadn't heard these terms before but apparently they are real terms (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430578)

Comment: its dynamic....

Comment: possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/40431257/3694269

Comment: @pkpnd There are innumerable facets/semantics that can be considered when looking at that code. For instance, one can think of the data types, arithmetic operation, number ranges, etc. One can't label as static or dynamic facts about a random piece of code, you need to look at particular behavior area (is the syntax valid, how is the compiler going to validate types, how is the calculation going to take place, what inference is going to be applicable, what type conversions will take place, etc.). In short, this is too broad and cannot be answered in any precise way.